# Run time error when browse Central administration in sharpeoint 2016 app server

Tags: 2016, central-administration, sharepoint-on-prem

central administration not working suddenly where all search components deployed and below error in event viewer

```
Application information: 
    Application domain:  
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\33948\ 
    Machine name: XXXX 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6152 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: MXX

Exception information: 
    Exception type: FileLoadException 
    Exception message: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this happen but most of the time it was cleared after performing the IIS reset on the server. So try to IIS reset on the server and test again.

another solution is clear the asp cache `"First stop the site in IIS. Then clear out the ASP.NET Temporary Files folder that relates to your site (default location is under C:WindowsMicrosoft.NETFrameworkv2.0.50727Temporary ASP.NET Files). Then start IIS and try browsing to the site."`
Source: [Here is good article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30494.sharepoint-troubleshooting-loading-this-assembly-would-produce-a-different-grant-set-from-other-instances-0x80131401.aspx) to read about the same error